# Perl Programming in Shell

Tags: linux, perl

My Expectation:
I have to use the following command to send the value of first argument to all the files calling perl.pl file.

```
./perl.pl 1
```

The one is read using the following file: (perl.pl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Black;
use strict;
use warnings;

#subroutines
sub get_x();

#variables
our $XE = -1;

  my ($param1, $param2, $param3) = @ARGV;
  my $x = get_x();

  sub get_x()
  {
  $XE = $param1;
  return $XE;

  }

exit;
```

Then I wrote another script which performs some code base on the input to perl.pl (0 or 1).
The file is ./per.pl and I invoke in from linux terminal like this: ./per.pl
Here is the code I wrote for it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require "perl.pl";

my $xd = Black::get_x();
if ($xd ==1){
print $xd;}
else {
print "5";
}
```

exit;

But this is what I get when I write these commands:

```
./perl.pl 1
```

I tried to print it and it prints 1...removed the print like from the code in this case

```
./per.pl
```

And now I get nothing. I would like the 1 getting printed out but no it doesn't

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You get nothing?  Black::get_x() always returns undef when invoked by `per.pl`, so the test always fails, so it always prints 5.  Maybe you don't see the output because you're not printing a newline.  try `./per.pl; echo` at the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we get started, you cannot possibly get the output you say you get because you tell the process to `exit` when the module is executed by `require`, so `Black::get_x()` is never reached. Change `exit;` to `1;`.

---

Now on to your question. If I understand correctly, you want to pass a value to one process via its command line, and fetch that value by executing the same script without the parameter.

You did not even attempt to pass the variable from one process to another, so it shouldn't be a surprise that it doesn't work. Since the two processes don't even exist at the same time, you'll need to store the value somewhere such as the file system.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $conf_file = "$ENV{HOME}/.black";
my $default = -1;

sub store {
    my ($val) = @_;
    open(my $fh, '>', $conf_file) or die $!;
    print $fh "$val\n";
    return $val;
}

sub retrieve {
    open(my $fh, '<', $conf_file)
        or do {
            return $default if $!{ENOENT};
            die $!;
        };

    my $val = <$fh>;
    chomp($val);
    return $val;
}

my $xd = @ARGV ? store($ARGV[0]) : retrieve();
print("$xd\n");
```

Comment: I initially misunderstood the question. Updated my answer.

Comment: Hello, I really appreciate your response. Can you please explain it a little too. Like what the commands do. Thanks

Comment: can u explain my $conf_file = "$ENV{HOME}/.black"; and  my ($val) = @_; and return $default if $!{NOENT}; I think I understand the rest that u write to a file and then u read from it.

Comment: Assigns `/home/ikegami/.black` to $conf_file. // The sub takes one argument and places it in `$val`. // Returns the default value (-1) if the error is ENOENT (file not found).